# Rendering engine to load 3D model into Qt

Tags: qt, 3d, rendering

I need an appropriate rendering engine to render a 3D model into Qt, and use Qt then as an event handler to this model. Thank you.

Comment: A bit broad a question. What models? What file formats to support? What do you want to do with the model? Event handler to the model?

Comment: As you are new here, remember to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: I have a 3D human body model that been manipulated by some Matlab processes (stretching, changing some body features, etc..) and I want to render this model in Qt, to build my own application UI.
Some thing like this tool: http://www.makehuman.org/

Answer (score 3):

As for the rendering engine, you can go several directions, but I'll mention two. Qt comes with an OpenGL widget. You could make use of this by either:

- writing your own rendering code to render your model using OpenGL

or

- making use of a rendering engine/framework which has it's own Qt Widget (possibly derived from Qt's OpenGl widget). I know [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) has Qt integration available. And I seem to remember [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) does as well. This just to mention two options. Just Google for Qt and your favorite engine and you'll most likely find something suitable. And if not, it is usually not that difficult to write your own integration if you feel like it.

Whichever option is more suitable for you depends on the exact specification of what you're trying to achieve. You probably know that better than we do.

As for the event handling, you might want to be a bit more specific as to what you mean.